# Remove comma from moderncv's \cventry

Tags: macros, punctuation, moderncv

This image shows the excerpt of a [CV](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4025249/stefanie_cv/cv_stefanie_v3.pdf) produced with the `moderncv` document class:

[image]

Notice that after the bold text there is a comma. This seems to be produced automatically. How can I stop this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The entry you're showing is produce with `\cventry`, so we want to change the definition of this macro. It is defined in `moderncvstyleclassic.sty`. All I did is copy it into my preamble verbatim and remove the undesired comma. (In the MWE, I actually copied the line and commented out the original, to make the change recognizable.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
%%%
% the following definition is from the file moderncvstyleclassic.sty
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
%   \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}% I changed this line (with comma) ...
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{ {\slshape#4}}% ... into this one (without comma).
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
%%%
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\begin{document}
\section{Education}
\cventry{December 2012}{Master of Science in Chocolatology}{University of Candyland}{Sugartown}{A+ with Golden Gummy Bear}{I am the chocolate-man.} 
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 13):

instead of redefining the whole command yourself also consider using `xpatch`:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd\cventry{,}{}{}{}
```

this line replaces the first occurence in the macro text of `,` by the empty string - i.e. removes it.

Here is also [a nice documentation of how the command works](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152773/please-tutor-the-usage-of-patchcmd-and-xpatch).

Comment: How do i remove comma from all macros?

Answer (score 8):

Obvious comment, but in case you want to be able to switch between having and not having the comma, you can define a new command `\cventrynocomma` like this:

```
\newcommand*{\cventrynocomma}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{ {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{ #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{ #6}%
    \strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

Comment: This worked brilliantly for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the file moderncvstyleclassic.sty, remove the comma and dot like following:

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{ {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{ #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{ #6}%
    \strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

It will remove the auto generated commas and dot from the \cventry.

Comment: You should not change files you don't own.

Comment: Can I say it "customization"? Otherwise, how can I use it? Most of the files we use are written by someone else. @Johannes-b

Comment: Copy rge relevant code to your preamble.

Comment: Just to clarify for future readers, the reason "You should not change files you don't own" is that, with the next update to the package, your changes would be overwritten. By copying the relevant code to your preamble and editing it there, your document will look the same before and after the package update.