# Automatically return list of all uses of a command, without repeats e.g. \compound using chemstyle

Tags: macros, numbering, comma-separated-list, chemstyle

I'd like to automatically generate a comma separated list of all occurrences in my .tex file of a particular command.

Specifically, I want to ensure the correct numbering of chemical structures using the `chemstyle` package and `\compound{<structurelabel>}` in a long document by initially, invisibly declaring all structures, in the order they appear in the mainmatter via `\compound*{<1ststructurelabel>,<2ndstructurelabel>,...}`. [N.B. incorrect numbering can occur because of the inclusion of references to structures within headings and hence the TOC].

I am aware of [this fantastic online tool](http://www.jkwchui.com/Apps/schemerefParse/schemeref-parse.html), but find that it sometimes works perfectly and at other times doesn't respond at all (as far as I am aware I attempt to use it in exactly the same way each time), so would love an alternative.

Here is a MWE to hopefully make my query clearer (I use Texmaker and MiKTeX, with ActivePerl installed and shell-escape enabled):

```
\documentclass[oneside,fontsize=13pt,parskip=full]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrhack,graphicx,libertine,lipsum,caption,setspace,gensymb,amsmath,amsthm,array,lastpage,color,upgreek,soul,multirow}
\usepackage[left=1.75in,right=1in,top=1.3in,bottom=1.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric,
autocite=superscript,
url=false,
doi=false,
natbib=true
]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{bibintoc}[\bibname]{%
\addchap{#1}%
}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\RawFloats[figure,scheme]
\newcommand\fnote[1]{\captionsetup{font=small,skip=4pt}\caption*{#1}}
\newcommand*{\myfont}{\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\mytilde}{\raise.17ex\hbox{$\scriptstyle\sim$}}
\definecolor{ilinks}{rgb}{0.356,0.064,0.796}
\renewcommand*{\schemerefformat}{%
\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\color{magenta}\textit%
}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={color=ilinks}}
\captionsetup[scheme]{labelfont={color=ilinks}}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont={color=ilinks}}
\addtokomafont{part}{\fontsize{43}{1.5em}\mdseries\scshape}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\Huge\scshape}
\addtokomafont{section}{\mdseries\fontsize{19}{22}\normalfont\itshape}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont\mdseries\scshape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{main}{ %
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}}
\newcommand{\markedsection}[2]{\section[#2]{#2%
\sectionmark{#1}}
\sectionmark{#1}}
\newcommand{\markedchapter}[2]{\chapter[#2]{#2%
\chaptermark{#1}}
\chaptermark{#1}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\newcommand*{\TitleFont}{\mdseries\scshape
  \fontsize{43}{1.5em}
  \selectfont}
\newcommand*{\AuthorFont}{\sffamily%
  \fontsize{25}{15}%
  \selectfont}
\newcommand*{\DateFont}{%
  \fontsize{19}{1.2em}%
  \selectfont}
\newcommand*{\PublishersFont}{%
  \fontsize{19}{1.2em}%
  \selectfont}      
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Section}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}
\renewcommand*{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}
\newcolumntype{P}%
            {>{\centering\arraybackslash}%
            m{2cm}%
            <{}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]%
            {>{\centering\arraybackslash}%
            p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}%
            {@{}m{0pt}%
            @{}}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\section{Reference to \compound{one}}

Jumbled references to \compound{one}, then \compound{two}, \compound{three} and \compound{four}.  Now repeats of \compound{three} and \compound{one}.

\section{Reference to \compound{four}}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Hi. Not what you ask for but maybe interesting nonetheless: the [`chemnum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemnum) package for numbering of chemical compounds has a “showlabels” option for visual checking of labels

Comment: @cgnieder Thanks for the info - I did temporarily attempt to use chemnum with chemstyle but as a complete novice couldn't get my document to compile `successfully’.  I’ve decided not to update my question with that attempt as I think the problems I had didn’t relate to my original query, but will include if anyone requests.

Comment: BTW: do you know that `\compound` has an optional `+` for usage in section headings and the like? With the `+` option the number is only read but not defined. This is described in the manual for `chemcompounds`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to patch `\compound`: the `etoolbox` package contains commands that allow one to prepend or append code to an already defined command. See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152811/55879) for a good explanation of this.

In order to get a comma-separated list, we'll patch the command to write its argument to a file whenever it is called:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newwrite\myfile 
\immediate\openout\myfile=\jobname.foo 
\apptocmd{\compound}{\write\myfile{#1,}}{}{}
```

Here's a small, full example. In this code, `\term` marks definitions, but also handles indexing automatically.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\usepackage{etoolbox} 

\newwrite\myfile 
\immediate\openout\myfile=\jobname.foo 

\newcommand{\term}[1]{\emph{#1}\index{#1}} 
\apptocmd{\term}{\write\myfile{#1,}}{}{} 

\makeindex 

\begin{document} 
The \term{mitochondria} are the powerhouse of the cell. \term{Anaphora}
is the repetition of a word at the start of several phrases. A
\term{circle} is a set of points in the plane equidistant from a
given point, called its \term{center}.\footnote{The distance
itself is called the \term{radius}.} 

\printindex 
\end{document}
```

If this file is called `defn.tex`, then after compiling, `defn.foo` contains a comma-separated list of all of the arguments I provided to `\term`:

```
mitochondria,
Anaphora,
circle,
center,
radius,
```