# list of all used commands in compiled *.tex-documents

Tags: macros, environments, fun, latex-misc

Is it possible to get a list of *all the commands used in the compiled documents*? I mean, if I use in my various `.tex`-documents commands such as `\emph`, `\section`, `\cite`, `\begin`, `\documentclass`, `\footnote`, and `\MyCommandX`, can I generate a list similar to the following?

```
\begin
\cite
\documentclass
\emph
\footnote
\MyCommandX
\section
```

Similar question: [Automatically return list of all uses of a command, without repeats e.g. \compound using chemstyle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220767/12277)

Comment: You just mean the commands used explicitly in the source, not used in definitions? Any editor ought to be able to show that I'd have thought.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I am using `TexShop`. It never occurred to me that this might be a feature of the editor. In any case, I don't see anything similar in TexShop. Any other editors which have that feature on mac?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Taking a file, `xyz.tex`, I just used as an answer to another question

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| >{$}c<{$} | c | c | c | c | c | c |c |}
\cline{2-8}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{7}{c|}{\rule{0mm}{0.4cm}{figure1 put here}}\\ \hline
\rule[-.5cm]{0mm}{1.2cm} x & -0.01 & -0.001 & -0.0001 & 0 & 0.0001 & 0.001 & 0.01 \\\hline
\rule[-.5cm]{0mm}{1.2cm} f(x) & 1.99499 & 1.9995 & 1.99995 & ? & 2.00005 & 2.0005 & 2.00499\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{7}{c|}{\rule{0mm}{0.4cm}\text{figure2 put here}}\\\cline{2-8}
\end{tabular}
addsomething with \emph{\$ and \^{a}}

\end{document}
```

Then a simple command line such as

```
 egrep  -o '\\[a-zA-Z]+|\\[^a-zA-Z]' xyz.tex | sort | uniq
```

produces

```
\$
\\
\^
\begin
\cline
\documentclass
\emph
\end
\hline
\multicolumn
\rule
\text
\usepackage
```

That's using unix-ish tools (although I'm on windows) but any editor ought to be able to do the same thing.

Comment: that was quick -- and seems so simple.

Comment: @ClintEastwood You'll feel that often when you see these command line tools.

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled on this question and thought that it would be amusing to list the control sequences *within* the document itself.  Of course, it suffices to input verbatim the listing produced by D.C.’s answer, but let’s say we want to do it all in a single run; this can be done in the following way:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand*{\meta}[1]{\(\langle\textit{#1}\rangle\)}

\title{The \TeX\ control sequences\\
    used in this document}
\author{A.~U.~Thor}



\begin{document}

\maketitle

What follows is an alphabetized list of the names of all the \TeX\ control
sequences used in this same document:

\begin{flushleft}
\ttfamily
\catcode`\^ = 12
\catcode`$ = 0
\catcode`\\ = 12
$obeylines
$input{|"egrep  -o '\\[a-zA-Z]+|\\[^a-zA-Z]' $jobname.tex | sort | uniq"}
$end{flushleft}

Note that \verb*|\ | is handled correctly, but \verb|\|\meta{CR} is not.
(We have included a \verb|\|\meta{CR} right here:~$\to$\
!)
Note also that the alfabetical ordering used by \texttt{sort} is somewhat
questionable, and that, of course, control sequences beginning with non-standard
escape characters, like \verb|$obeylines| or \verb|$input|, are not recognized.

\end{document}
```

Of course, this example must be compiled with the shell-escape feature enabled.

### Addition

Here’s the promised refined version (see the “comment to myself”, below):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{The \TeX\ control sequences\\
    used in this document}
\author{A.~U.~Thor}

\newcommand*{\meta}[1]{\(\langle\textit{#1}\rangle\)}
\newcommand*{\CR}{\meta{CR}}

\newcommand*{\ListMyOwnCSNames}{%
    \begin{flushleft}%
        \ttfamily
        \def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12\relax}%
        \dospecials
        \obeylines
        \input{|"\CommandLine\jobname"}%
    \end{flushleft}%
}
\newcommand*{\CommandLine}{} % let's behave well and declare the name
\begingroup
    \catcode`\^ = 12
    \catcode`\$ = 0
    \catcode`\\ = 12
    $gdef $CommandLine #1{%
        egrep  -o '\\[a-zA-Z]+|\\[^a-zA-Z]' #1.tex | sort | uniq%
    }
$endgroup



\begin{document}

\maketitle

What follows is an alphabetized list of the names of all the \TeX\ control
sequences used in this same document:

\ListMyOwnCSNames

Note that \verb*|\ | is handled correctly, but \verb|\|\CR\ is not.
(We have included a \verb|\|\CR\ right here:~$\to$\
!)
Note also that the alfabetical ordering used by \texttt{sort} is somewhat
questionable, and that, of course, control sequences beginning with non-standard
escape characters, like \verb|$gdef| or \verb|$endgroup|, are not recognized.

Let's try a few special characters.  It costs 100\$.  Procter \& Gamble.  You
are the~\#1!.  De~l'H\^{o}pital.  A variable named \textit{total\_cost}.
A~10\%~discount.  \emph{Muchas gracias, se\~{n}orita!} (I~hope the Spanish is 
correct!)

Moreover: let \( P = \{\,x\mid\mbox{$x$ is prime}\,\} \), and\\a line break.

\end{document}
```

Please note that I wouldn’t have dared to write an answer like this, hadn’t the question already been catalogued under the “fun” tag.

Comment: A comment to myself: other “special” characters should be `\catcode`d 12 too.  Imagine the document uses `\_`, `\%`, etc.  Also, it’s better to switch to an indirect approach, in order to “decouple” the `\catcode` regime: define a macro in the preamble, etc.; shall fix tomorrow.  BTW: `\$` *does* work as the code stands, but produces a somewhat unexpected result: can you guess what it is?