# \hspace before \section?

Tags: spacing

I would like to add a space before a section heading.

I have tried:

```
\hspace[*]{5pt}\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{45}{40}\selectfont  
\fontspec{Mathilde}}
```

unsuccessfully. I realise that Latex usually discards white space at the start of a line e.g. a section heading.

I would appreciate any pointers how I may achieve a space before a section heading of 0.5 inches.

```
\documentclass[11pt,english,british,twoside,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\title{\mytitle}
\author{}
\date{}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{flushright}
{\huge \mytitle}
\par\end{flushright}{\huge \par}
\end{titlepage}

\begin{titlepage}
\noindent\includegraphics[width=4in,height=2in]{../img/titr_ben_sig}
\vspace*{0.5in}
\begin{flushright}
\Huge{Tears in the Rain}
\par\end{flushright}{\Huge \par}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\emph{Copyright}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\textcopyright{ 2014 Ben Francis All rights reserved.}
\end{center}
\vspace*{0.5in}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\paperwidth}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\vspace*{0.5in}
\begin{center}
ISBN:
\end{center}
\vspace*{0.2in}
\begin{center}
A CIP Record for this book is available from the British
Library.
\end{center}
\vspace*{0.1in}
\begin{center}
Typeset in \LaTeXe
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\tableofcontents

\input{matter.tex}

\end{document}[/MWE]

My style file is:

[MWE]
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}
\usepackage{lettrine}
%\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,footsepline=.25pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {../img/} }
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\slshape}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalsize}
\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\normalsize}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}% rm for chapter headings
%\addtokomafont{trajon pro}{\rmfamily}
%\ohead{\pagemark} %Page Number
%\ihead{\mytitle} %Book Title
\chead{\textbf {Ben Francis}}
\ofoot{} %Author Name
\ifoot{} % Chapter Number
\lehead{\textbf \pagemark}
%\cehead{Ben Francis}
\rohead{\textbf \pagemark}
\cohead{\textbf {\mytitle}}
\setkomafont{section}{\textit}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\linespread{1.05}
\parindent=0.25in
\parskip=2pt
%removes overrun on outside margin
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\tolerance=1000
\hyphenpenalty=1000
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} %clear font, typographers quote marks
\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=5.06in,paperheight=7.81in,
verbose,
tmargin=0.75in,
bmargin=0.75in,
inner=0.75in,
outer=0.5in,
headheight=0.1in,
headsep=0.15in,
footskip=0.45in,
twoside}
\newcommand{\mytitle}{Tears in the Rain} 
\newcommand{\emptx}[1]{\textit{#1}}

%Add space above chapter titles
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\normalsize}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{25pt}{1pt}%Second number changes space
%amount

\hspace[*]{5pt}\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{45}{40}\selectfont
\fontspec{Mathilde}}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\small}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\small}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalsize}
\setkomafont{subparagraph}{\normalsize}
```

Comment: I think you have your numbers reversed for `\fontsize`. But what about `\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\hspace*{0.5in}\thesection\autodot\enskip}`?  (Note that I don't often use the KOMA classes, even though I always tell myself I should.)

Comment: No luck - nothing changes....

Comment: Hi, I have tried various combinations of your solution but, the 'section' remains fixed as before. Am I right in thinking that it is possible to override the LaTeX default behaviour of ignoring changes to section commands if they fall at the start of a line?

Comment: Don't all new sections 'fall at the start of the life'? I don't really understand what you mean. The line in the above example that starts `\hspace[*]{5pt}` is not correct, and should not be used in the preamble. The command `\fontsize` has the numbers in the wrong order.  The code you have provided includes no `\section` command that I can see. Most of the code you have provided is completely irrelvant to the problem of getting the `\section`s properly spaced for your layout. "No luck - nothing changes" is unfortunately not very helpful: we need to see a complete example to understand better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to set the `indent` of the section title. Using this command you can also change the font:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  indent=.5in,
  font=\fontsize{45}{40}\selectfont\mdseries\mathilde
]{section}
```

Note that I have reduced your code for the following example:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\linespread{1.05}
\setlength\parindent{.25in}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\mathilde{Mathilde}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

    \RedeclareSectionCommand[
      indent=.5in,
      font=\fontsize{45}{40}\selectfont\mdseries\mathilde
    ]{section}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

---

Additional remarks:

- It is not recommended to use `titlesec` with a KOMA-Script class. You will get warnings. Use `\RedeclareSectionCommand` and other KOMA-Script possibilities instead.
- Do not set a `\parskip` manually. KOMA-Script classes know a `parskip` option with different values. Note that it is unusual to use a `\parindent` and a `\parskip`. If you really want set `\parindent` to 2pt use the KOMA-Script command `\setparsizes{.25in}{2pt}{0pt plus 1fil}`. But this `\parskip` may cause your problem in [Book Layout in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/282799/43317).
- Use `\addtokomafont` and `\setkomafont` to change the font of the header and the page number in the header.

Comment: First, Thank you all for your help! I've now solved my problem with the book layout thanks, largely to your support and help. Secondly, May I take this opportunity to wish you all a Very Happy and Peaceful New Year! Mike

Answer (score 2):

i'm not a user of the koma classes, but the structure of the sectioning
commands is generally parallel across document classes.

this is the definition of `\section` for `scrbook`:

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi
    \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@section}%
}
```

what you want to do is change the argument `{\z@}` after the `{1}`
to be `5pt` (or whatever amount of indentation you want).  this can
be done either with `\renewcommand` or by using the "patch" mechanism
as described in [Please tutor the usage of patchcmd and xpatch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152773/579).

**edit:** as requested by the op, here are the details of the two change
methods.  first, redefining the complete command:

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{5pt}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi
    \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@section}%
}
```

here, the change is made by a patch; this form requires an additional
package:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\section}
  {{1}{\z@}}
  {{1}{5pt}}
  {}{}
```

`5pt` seems very small to me.  the width of the usual paragraph indentation for this class is `1em` which, for 10pt text, would typically be `10pt`.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I do not understand your advice. I am an author, publishing with LaTeX, and have very little knowledge of the finer points of LaTeX :-). Could you explain a little more please?

Comment: AFAIK this is not the definition of `\section` in KOMA-Script version 3.19a (current on CTAN).