# \hspace before \section and \subsection

Tags: macros, spacing, sectioning

How to place `\hspace{}` before `\section{}` and `\subsection{}`? I am using an `\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}`.
I want make custom command for `\section{}` and `\subsection{}` with different `\hspace` value. How to do it? Help!

Comment: what is `\RedeclareSectionCommand[` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Its if from package `mystyle`. I just shown it because its been in [famous ansver](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269154/hspace-before-section) to my question already but it does not suit me.

Comment: that is using koma but you said you are using article, you have not shown mystyle and you did not reference the previous answer in your question.  You should really define any commands you show being used. Preferably by making the example a complete test document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Damn i really messed up everything, its realy not from `mystyle`, thanks for note.

Comment: you can still edit the question to make it more understandable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very hard to understand the question, which just has a fragment of code using an unshown package, and an undefined command, and nothing else. however I think you want this which just adds `\hspace*{}` to a copy of `\section` from `article.cls`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\sectionx[1]{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\hspace*{#1}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
aaa
\sectionx{1cm}{Another section}
aaa
\sectionx{.5cm}{Yet another section}
aaa
\section{A final section}
aaa

\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thank You a lot!