# Table caption not left aligned in revtex

Tags: tables, captions, align, revtex

I am currently writing an APS article and use:

```
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,nofootinbib,
]{revtex4-1}
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\PassOptionsToPackage{linktocpage}{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperindex,breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{array}
```

My figure captions are left aligned, as they should be. The table captions, however, are centered if I use the following code:

```
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{table*}[t]
  \centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l l}
   \hline
   \hline
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \rule{0pt}{3ex} ...} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{...} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{...} \\
   \hline
... & ... & ... \\
    \hline
    \hline
    \end{tabular*}
    \caption{Centered caption.}\label{tab:1}
\end{table*}
}
```

How can I make the table captions left aligned (and above and not below the table) as well?

Comment: Are you sure that the table captions are not centred only because they are too short to fill a line?

Comment: The table captions are centered and they are too short to fill a line, yes. But even though they are short, I want them to be left aligned and not centered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `revtex4-1` document class do not offer an option to switch the unwanted behavior off, i.e. short captions are always centered. And since the `caption` package is not adapted to `revtex` yet one need to patch the responsible code for yourself, e.g.:

```
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \par
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \begingroup
   \small\rmfamily
   \sbox\@tempboxa{%
    \let\\\heading@cr
    \@make@capt@title{#1}{#2}%
   }%
   \@ifdim{\wd\@tempboxa >\hsize}{%
    \begingroup
     \samepage
     \flushing
     \let\footnote\@footnotemark@gobble
     \@make@capt@title{#1}{#2}\par
    \endgroup
   }{%
     \global \@minipagefalse
     \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\unhbox\@tempboxa\hfil}%
   }%
  \endgroup
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip
}%
```

could be patched to:

```
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \par
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \begingroup
   \small\rmfamily
    \begingroup
     \samepage
     \flushing
     \let\footnote\@footnotemark@gobble
     \@make@capt@title{#1}{#2}\par
    \endgroup
  \endgroup
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip
}
```

As complete example document:

```
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,nofootinbib,
]{revtex4-1}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makecaption[2]{%
  \par
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \begingroup
   \small\rmfamily
    \begingroup
     \samepage
     \flushing
     \let\footnote\@footnotemark@gobble
     \@make@capt@title{#1}{#2}\par
    \endgroup
  \endgroup
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text...

\begin{table}
  Test
  \caption{Test}
\end{table}

Some text...

\end{document}
```

A more elegant solution using `\patchcmd` offered by the `etoolbox` package [1]:

```
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,nofootinbib,
]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}{\@ifdim{\wd\@tempboxa >\hsize}}{\@firstoftwo}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text...

\begin{table}
  Test
  \caption{Test}
\end{table}

Some text...

\end{document}
```

But please be aware that patching internals of document classes or packages is usually a bad idea since internals are subject of change in future versions of the patched document class or package.

[1] See also: [Please tutor the usage of patchcmd and xpatch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152773/please-tutor-the-usage-of-patchcmd-and-xpatch)