# How do i make a document where \part is twosided but \chapter is not

Tags: chapters, double-sided, parts, single-sided

I want to make a document where `\part` *only* starts on left-sided pages when using `\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}`. However, `\chapter` should start on either left or right-sided pages.

I have not been able to find any material on how to do this, which is a first for my five years of doing LaTeX documents.

Does anyone know of a package that allows me to do something like this, or is there a way to move the `twoside` option to only effect `\part`?

In advance thank you for any help.

Comment: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to *start* the `\part` on odd pages (not left-sided, is it?) and keep `\chapter` to start on both even and odd pages.

You can do this by using the `\cleardoublepage` command which does the same thing as `\clearpage` but also adds a blank page if needed. You can then redefine the `\part` macro to call `\cleardoulepage` before executing the rest of its content.

```tex
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pretocmd{\part}{\cleardoublepage}{}{}
```

For more information on the `\pretocmd` macro, please refer to [egreg's excellent post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152811/117727).

---

#### MWE

Here's a minimal working example:

```tex
\documentclass[twoside, openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pretocmd{\part}{\cleardoublepage}{}{}

\begin{document}

\part{The beginning of a new era}
\chapter{The evolution}
\lipsum[1-6]

\part{Another era}
\chapter{The second evolution}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

Note the use of the `openany` option which opens any page for starting new chapters, as by default, a chapter will always start on odd pages.