# I want to remove "Springer Nature 2021 LATEX template" from my template

Tags: templates, springernature

How can I delete or replace "Springer Nature 2021 LATEX template" from my page?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which document class do you use? Is it for publishing in an springer journal?

Comment: if you are submitting to springer you should leave this in, if you are not submitting then you shouldn't use the springer journal class.

Comment: where can I find that springer journal class? I want to just change or delete it.

Comment: https://www.springernature.com/la/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support

Comment: ? You have presumably used it already to make the output you show surely? But the class is dispributed by a commercial publisher you should not be changing it, why not use `article` class instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the  file `sn-jnl.cls` (An authoring template for Springer Journal articles) it is established

> It may be distributed and/or modified under the  conditions of the
> LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3c  of this license or
> (at your option) any later version.

[The LaTeX Project Public License](https://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt)

> 5. If you are not the Current Maintainer of the Work, you may modify your copy of the Work, thus creating a Derived Work based on the Work,
>    and compile this Derived Work, thus creating a Compiled Work based on
>    the Derived Work.

As an exercise of patching commands, following the examples in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152811/161015
it might be possible to change the heading to something else  making a proper reference to  the author(s)/owner(s).

Add after the comment in the template `sn-article.tex`

`

```
%%<additional latex packages if required can be included here>
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\ps@headings}%% Regular Pages Style 
    {\hbox to \hsize{\hfill Springer Nature 2021 \LaTeX\ template\hfill}}
    {\hbox to \hsize{\hfill Based on  Springer Nature \LaTeX\ template\hfill}}
    {}
    {}
    \patchcmd{\ps@titlepage}%% Opening Page Style   
    {\hbox to \hsize{\hfill Springer Nature 2021 \LaTeX\ template\hfill}}
    {\hbox to \hsize{\hfill Based on  Springer Nature \LaTeX\ template\hfill}}
    {}
    {}
    \makeatother
```

[image: b]

[image: a]

**UPDATED** to `remove`  Springer Nature etc. from every page see
[from every page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/647318/161015)

Comment: This not an answer to the question of how to *remove* the header, just the replace part...and it doesn't work (for me).  Is there a simple way to just delete it?

Comment: @AaronBramson - Just replace the 3rd argument of `\patchcmd` -- here: `{\hbox to \hsize{\hfill Based on  Springer Nature \LaTeX\ template\hfill}}` -- with `{}`.

Comment: Yes, well, if I run it as is, or change that text to a blank, the document is unchanged.  Possibly the issue is that this header also appears in a `\def\ps@titlepage{` block that isn't caught by the `\patchcmd` as written.  I ended up editting the cls file directly