# How to remove the "Springer Nature 2021 LATEX template" header from my manuscript

Tags: header-footer, templates, springernature

I am using the Springer Nature template based on the guidelines of the journal I'm submitting to, but I can't find any information on how to get rid of the annoying and horrible header that Springer put on the page header.  I need to (and everybody wants to) get rid of that garbage.

Basically this question was already asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617641/i-want-to-remove-springer-nature-2021-latex-template-from-my-template), but that question is asking to remove OR replace, and I just want to get rid of it.  Also, there is only one answer to one part of that question (the replace part), and that solution doesn't even work (for me).

Looking through the style class file, I found where they inserted that text (two places), and so I can change or remove the text in the `.cls` file without breaking the template.

I just needed to remove that annoying header, and editing the `.cls` file worked.  However, it would be better if there was a solution to override that header in the `.tex` file (as is partially done in the linked, similar question), that robustly worked.  Is there a way to hide/mask/override a header put these via the class file in a simple way in the `.tex` file?

Comment: sure, if it worked.  I managed to find where it is in the cls file and removed the text there, but (like the partial answer to the other question) it would be nice if there were a way in the tex file to override the command to prevent it from rendering in the manuscript.

Comment: @Mico I already linked to that question and it did not work for me.  Specifically, running it makes no change to the document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  It may be intentional by the publisher, or incompetence, but either way I don't want a header on my manuscript declaring it to be a template.  And the solution I linked to would be fine if it worked, but as I state clealy in my question, that method did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this again using version 2019/11/18 of `sn-jnl`. Removing the legend is straightforward.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}
{\hbox to \hsize{\hfill Springer Nature 2021 \LaTeX\ template\hfill}}
{\hbox to \hsize{\hfill Based on  Springer Nature \LaTeX\ template\hfill}}
{}
{}
\patchcmd{\ps@titlepage}
{\hbox to \hsize{\hfill Springer Nature 2021 \LaTeX\ template\hfill}}
{\hbox to \hsize{\hfill Based on  Springer Nature \LaTeX\ template\hfill}}
{}
{}
\makeatother
```