# I want to remove "Springer Nature 2021 LATEX template" from my template ON EVERY PAGE

Tags: templates, springernature

My question relates to the one someone already asked here: [I want to remove "Springer Nature 2021 LATEX template" from my template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617641/i-want-to-remove-springer-nature-2021-latex-template-from-my-template)

Thanks to the advice from this thread, namely, by using the following code:

```
\usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}
{\hbox to \hsize{\hfill Springer Nature 2021 \LaTeX\ template\hfill}}
{\hbox to \hsize{}}
{}
{}
\patchcmd{\ps@titlepage}
{\hbox to \hsize{\hfill Springer Nature 2021 \LaTeX\ template\hfill}}
{\hbox to \hsize{}}
{}
{}
\makeatother
```

I managed to delete "Springer Nature 2021 LATEX template" from my template on the opening page and the even pages but not on the odd pages. How do I fix this?

Comment: But to quote the second comment on that question: "if you are submitting to springer you should leave this in, if you are not submitting then you shouldn't use the springer journal class."

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You can make the code block recognizable as code by highlighting it and then clicking on the `{}` icon above the question box.  (This greatly improves readability.)

Answer (score 2):

The code "`{\hbox to \hsize{\hfill Springer Nature 2021 \LaTeX\ template\hfill}}`" occurs twice in the definition of `\ps@headings` in the sn-jnl document class file: once when setting up the headers for even pages, and once when setting them up for odd pages.

The command `\patchcmd` from etoolbox you're using replaces only the first occurrence of this code with the replacement code, so only affects even pages.

But once the first patch is applied, you can just do it again to replace the second occurrence:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}
{\hbox to \hsize{\hfill Springer Nature 2021 \LaTeX\ template\hfill}}
{\hbox to \hsize{}}
{}
{}
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}
{\hbox to \hsize{\hfill Springer Nature 2021 \LaTeX\ template\hfill}}
{\hbox to \hsize{}}
{}
{}
\patchcmd{\ps@titlepage}
{\hbox to \hsize{\hfill Springer Nature 2021 \LaTeX\ template\hfill}}
{\hbox to \hsize{}}
{}
{}
\makeatother
```

However, I should note that overall I agree with the sentiment expressed in the comments of both threads: if you're submitting to a Springer journal, then keep these headers in. If you're not submitting to a Springer journal, it is unclear why you'd want to use their document class.