# Tables caption front was too small

Tags: tables, captions

When I create the tables, the front of the table caption was too small than the others, I don't know how to solve this problem? Does someone know this?

```
\documentclass[utf8]{frontiers_suppmat} % for all articles
\usepackage{url,hyperref,lineno,microtype}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\onecolumn
\firstpage{1}

\title[Supplementary Material]{{\helveticaitalic{Supplementary Material}}}


\maketitle
\section{Supplementary Data}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{The Ct values of qPCR for 23 samples and their copy numbers.}
\label{stab2}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cll} 
\toprule
Sample Number & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Ct value}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Copies}} \\ 
\midrule
1               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{22.78}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20562.22}    \\
2               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{25.28}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3574.30}     \\
3               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20.45}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{105021.11}   \\
4               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{29.34}    & 208.52                          \\
5               & 25.44                        & 3195.65                         \\
6               & 19.14                        & 262695.65                       \\
7               & 21.1                         & 66635.89                        \\
8               & /                            & /                               \\
9               & 19.66                        & 182556.87                       \\
10              & 23                           & 17627.90                        \\
11              & 18.31                        & 469604.80                       \\
12              & 21.4                         & 54016.05                        \\
13              & 18.59                        & 386034.52                       \\
14              & 21.51                        & 50013.60                        \\
15              & 17.24                        & 993025.70                       \\
16              & /                            & /                               \\
17              & 20.87                        & 78273.91                        \\
18              & 19.39                        & 220528.66                       \\
19              & 16.42                        & 1762790.12                      \\
20              & 30.75                        & 77.73                           \\
21              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{24.03}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8572.96}     \\
22              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{33.18}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{14.19}       \\
23              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{15.46}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3451389.08}  \\
NTC             & \multicolumn{1}{c}{/}        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{/}           \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site! These things are typically configured via the document class and/or packages, so without a complete minimal working example, it is difficult to help you.

Comment: No, I am not going to another site to edit code for you. If you want help here, I suggest that you post a complete example here.

Comment: I re-edit the code and post the example, Could you fix this?

Comment: The class (which is not standard, but I think I found while searching) has a `\footnotesize` inside its definition of `\@tablecaption`. This can probably be patched (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152773/52406), but I don't know how to do that properly.

Comment: @Linnea give a new link on You project because I can't follow Your link "Restricted, sorry you don’t have permission to load this page."

Comment: @winnienotthepooh, I shared a new link which can be edited: [link]https://www.overleaf.com/4781856441csjhppbqpqhs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To long for the comment

- I suppose, that you like to publish your article in journal, which use `frontiers_suppmat` document class
- This document class is designed so that article used it will meet their formatting requirements. Apparently they assure this with hardwired styles, so don't try to change caption style. They will take a care for final looks of artice.

*Off-topic*:
I do not know the context of your table, however you may liked the following its design:

[image]

```
\documentclass[utf8]{frontiers_suppmat} % for all articles
\usepackage{lineno,microtype}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
%\onecolumn

\section{Supplementary Data}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{The Ct values of qPCR for 23 samples and their copy numbers.}
\label{stab2}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.0]
                S[table-format=2.2]
                S[table-format=7.2]}
    \toprule
{\thead{Sample\\ Number}} 
    & {\thead{Ct value}}
                &   {\thead{Copies}}    \\
    \midrule
1   &   22.78   &   20562.22            \\
2   &   25.28   &    3574.30            \\
3   &   20.45   &  105021.11            \\
4   &   29.34   &     208.52            \\
5   &   25.44   &     3195.65           \\
6   &   19.14   &   262695.65           \\
7   &   21.1    &    66635.89           \\
8   &   {/}     &   {/}                 \\
9   &   19.66   &   182556.87           \\
10  &   23      &    17627.90           \\
11  &   18.31   &   469604.80           \\
12  &   21.4    &    54016.05           \\
13  & 18.59     &   386034.52           \\
14  & 21.51     &    50013.60           \\
15  & 17.24     &   993025.70           \\
16  &   {/}     &   {/}                 \\
17  &   20.87   &    78273.91           \\
18  &   19.39   &   220528.66           \\
19  &   16.42   &  1762790.12           \\
20  &   30.75   &       77.73           \\
21  &   24.03   &     8572.96           \\
22  &   33.18   &       14.19           \\
23  &   15.46   &  3451389.08           \\
{NTC}   &   {/} &   {/}                 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the document preamble I reorganized (`hyperref` should be loaded last). Added are two packages: `makecell` and `siunitx`, which enables better column headers formatting and aligning numbers at decimal points.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance, this is indeed the format I was looking for, but I think your suggestion is very good.